# show off borders in GXT 3

Tags: gwt, gxt

I have problem in **GXT 3** with set off borders in containers. I create several ContentPanels without any borders and headers, as a result they work excellent. But then I'm trying to add container (f.e. BorderLayoutContainer) and also set off container borders, some borders are still where:

[image: borders and background]

So what I want is clean white **page without any borders**. This is my code with container:

```
public class Page {

public Widget asPage()
{
    BorderLayoutContainer container = new BorderLayoutContainer();

    try
    {
        container.setId("#MainContainer");
        container.setBorders(false);

        container.setWestWidget(asDashBoard(), new BorderLayoutContainer.BorderLayoutData());

        VerticalLayoutContainer vlcforRight = new VerticalLayoutContainer();
        vlcforRight.setBorders(false);
        vlcforRight.setId("#vlcRight");
        vlcforRight.add(asHeader(), new VerticalLayoutContainer.VerticalLayoutData(1, 0.3));
        vlcforRight.add(asMainView(), new VerticalLayoutContainer.VerticalLayoutData(1, 0.5));

        container.setCenterWidget(vlcforRight);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return container;
}}
```

which is simply added to viewport:

```
 Page page = new Page();

 Viewport viewport = new Viewport();

 viewport.add(page.asPage());

 RootLayoutPanel.get().add(viewport);
```

The functions *asDashBoard(), asMainView(), asHeader()* are the same:

```
private Widget asHeader()
{
    LayoutPanel lpHeader = null;
    try
    {
        lpHeader = new LayoutPanel();
        lpHeader.setId("#lpHeader");


        lpHeader.add(setTestWidgets());

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return lpHeader;
}
```

where LayoutPanel simply extended from ContentPanel with non-header and non-border style.

---

From my point of view, I don't set something for containers, nonetheless I haven't no idea what I miss. Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found my problem. When you want to set off ContentPanel borders, you should do this:

```
public class LayoutPanel extends ContentPanel {

public LayoutPanel()
{
    ...
    setBodyBorder(false);
    ...

}
```

}